# How do I parse CDG files on iOS

Tags: ios, parsing

Does anyone know how to parse CDG (karaoke) files on the iOS? Have found USKaraoke library but that one is quite old, for Mac and crashing

Comment: Perhaps you should try to figure out why it's crashing and edit your question to include what you discover.  A stack trace would be a good start, and any messages that appear in the debug console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are few links to help you start;

- http://jbum.com/cdg_revealed.html - Format Specifications
- http://shaunio.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-karaoke-cdg-disks-work.html -
  Additional information on how it works.
- https://github.com/martinb3/java_karaoke/blob/master/src/org/mbs3/jkaraoke/Packet.java - Java implementation of CDG parser, worth looking at.